# Accessing specific index in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say i have this

```
@using MvcApplication6.Models;
@model List<Employee>
```

I 
I have 5 rows/records of `Employee` and i passed it to my view. They have `id, firstname,lastname,gender,department`.

I know that i can use `foreach` to loop through all of them but what if i want to access a specific record from the list?

I get indexing error if i do something like this :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].firstname)
```

I just want to display a specific record from my page. What should i do to achieve that result?

**full code**

```
    @using MvcApplication6.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New record", "Create")
</p>

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model[0].firstname)

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Check departments", "Index", "Department")</p>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.department)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (Employee item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details","Details", "Employee", new { id=item.id },null) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Players[0])
        </td>

    </tr>


}

</table>
```

Comment: Are you certain that you actually have records in your list?

Comment: Yes because i am displaying them through tables.

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].firstname)` will NOT create an error if the model contains at least one item. But then your code snippet has `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model[0].firstname)` which will because  `Employee` does not have a property named `Model`. And NEVER use `@Html.LabelFor(model => Model[0].firstname)` (capital M) as per the answer you accepted (in some circumstances it will result in an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the property model on an instance of your collection.  Instead, simply reference the model by index to access the firstname property:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m[0].firstname)
```

The lambda expression exposes the Model, which in your case is a collection.  In addition, you should resolve your @model to `List<>` instead of `IEnumerable<>` to prevent lazy evaluation.

Comment: @DavidL, The real issue I assume is that the 'full code' snippet has `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model[0].firstname)` (and type of `Employee` does not have a property named `Model`) and that OP had not actually tried `@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].firstname)` despite the claim. But then again the question starts by saying its `@model List<Employee>` but then the later code shows `@model IEnumerable<Employee>` so who really knows :)

Comment: I did my best to address all the possible issues in this case :).  I actually suspect that the issue was IEnumerable, coupled with bad syntax.  Thanks for pointing out the error.